# Ui-router two states with same controller and template but different parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states that I want to share the same controller and view, but have different parents. The `userInfo` state will allow users to change their password / email / etc. And the `register` state is for users who have not logged in yet and need to create an account. These states share the same form inputs and similar functionality so I want to combine them in one view and use one controller for both.

The `userInfo` state needs `menu` as its parent so that the menu is available, whereas on `register` I do not want the menu to be present.

How can I accomplish this? I have looked into using an abstract state for both, but I have not seen any examples where one state has a different parent than the other.

```
        .state('userInfo', {
            url: '/userInfo',
            parent: 'menu',
            params: {
                id: null,
                name: null,
                email: null,
                password: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/userInfo/userInfo.view.html',
            controller: 'userInfoCtrl',
            data: {}
        })

        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            params: {
                email: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/userInfo/userInfo.view.html',
            controller: 'userInfoCtrl',
            data: {}
        })
```

Maybe I'm just wasting my time and I should just make separate controllers and views for each state?

Comment: The code you have shown looks like it should work.  What is not working?

Comment: @ChrisT It seems like angular binds a controller and view to one state the moment it is opened. So when I open one of these states, then try to go to the other, it does nothing. Doesn't give me an error message or anything.

Comment: but it does change the url?